# Question on singular value decompositon

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, svd

Given a matrix ${\bf{H}}\in \mathbb{C}^{M\times N}$, and suppose its singular value decomposition as ${\bf{H}}={\bf{U}}{\bf{\Sigma}}{\bf{V}}^H$, where ${\bf{U}}\in \mathbb{C}^{M\times M}$ and   ${\bf{V}}\in \mathbb{C}^{N\times N}$ are two unitatary matrices and ${\bf{\Sigma}}$ is an $M\times N$ rectangular diagonal matrix with non-negative real numbers on the diagonal.

My question is: does there exist a specifical decompostion pair ${\bf{U}}$ and ${\bf{V}}$, satisfying ${\bf{U}}$ is an identity matrix, i.e., ${\bf{U}}={\bf I}$? If it exists, then how to find the corresponding ${\bf{V}}$?

Comment: You might be interested in ``polar decomposition'': https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_decomposition

Comment: If such decomposition exists, then $\mathbf{H}\mathbf{H}^H$ would be diagonal.

Comment: If $U=I$, the first $\min(M,N)$ rows of $H$ mustl be mutually orthogonal and the other rows (if any) are zero. In this case, you may simply normalise the first $\min(M,N)$ rows and complete them to an orthogonal matrix to get $V^H$.

Comment: @uer1551    You are right, thanks.